# Full Date Range

Tags: oracle, plsql

1st time posting here, so sorry if I messed something up.
I'm trying to figure out how many units pre day are being used across multiple products given a date range.

So if I had a table like this:

| Product_id | Start_date | End_date | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07/07/2021 | 07/09/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 07/08/2021 | 07/10/2021 | 4 |
| 3 | 07/12/2021 | 07/12/2021 | 7 |

The output should be something like:

| Date | Units |
| --- | --- |
| 07/07/2021 | 2 |
| 07/08/2021 | 6 |
| 07/09/2021 | 6 |
| 07/10/2021 | 4 |
| 07/11/2021 | 0 |
| 07/12/2021 | 7 |

Comment: OK.  What have you attempted?

Comment: I was able to list dates and group/sum the units but only for the start and end dates, not the date in-between.  My example was bad for this, but if product_id 2 started on the 9th, then my output would show the 9th as 6 units, but for my example, my output shows 2.

Comment: Post what you have even though it does not produce the desired result. Since you say your example is bad, then perhaps you should change it.

Comment: @belayer I meant bad for that comment.  For my question, the example is fine.
So I simplified my question, because the final results are a little more complicated.  The current query I have probably won't make sense, so I didn't post it as I didn't want to confuse people or have people go off tangent of what I actually need.  But if I'm wrong, and it helps, I can add it.

Comment: I think you wanted to tag Oracle and SQL, not [PL/SQL](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/appdev/plsql.html) and [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  calendar as
  3    -- all dates between the first START_DATE and the last END_DATE.
  4    -- You need it for outer join with data you have.
  5    (select mindat + level - 1 as datum
  6     from (select min(start_date) mindat,
  7                  max(end_date)   maxdat
  8           from test
  9          )
 10     connect by level <= maxdat - mindat + 1
 11    )
 12  -- final query
 13  select c.datum,
 14         nvl(sum(t.units), 0) units
 15  from calendar c left join test t on c.datum between t.start_date and t.end_date
 16  group by c.datum
 17  order by c.datum;

DATUM           UNITS
---------- ----------
07/07/2021          2
07/08/2021          6
07/09/2021          6
07/10/2021          4
07/11/2021          0
07/12/2021          7

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```